# Play framework redirect to another host

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to write action to redirect to another host (localhost:3003) after some manipulation with data.

I use

```
Redirect("localhost:3003/localConclusion")
```

but instead of redirecting i got

```
http://localhost:9090/localConclusion/localhost:3003/localConclusion
```

I would like to ask for advice or links which can help me to solve my problem.

I use scala 2.11 & play framework 2.5

Comment: Side note: you are using very old versions of both Scala and Play, I'd recommend upgrading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a complete URL in the redirect, your browser or client will assume it's a relative redirect to the same site.

Just add `http://`:

```scala
Redirect("http://localhost:3003/localConclusion")
```